# Issue Running Imagick module (PHP 5.3.5, WAMP server 2.1e)

Tags: php, imagemagick, wamp

I have installed Wamp server 2.1e-32bit and ImageMagick-6.8.9-7-Q16-x86-dll in Windows Server 2008 R2-x64. After completed my installation process and run wamp server, i get a error message and Imagick not working

The error msg is:

```
"PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: imagick: Unable to initialize module
 Module compiled with build ID=API20090626,TS,VC9
 PHP compiled with build ID=API20090626,TS,VC6
 These options need to match in Unknown on line 0"
```

How to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try the [64-bit DLL](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/binaries/ImageMagick-6.8.9-7-Q16-x64-dll.exe) since you are running on Windows Server 2008 R2-x64 as recommended by the [doc](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows).

UPDATE:

If you don't already have the `php_imagick.dll` extension, you can download it from [here](https://pecl.php.net/package/imagick/3.1.2/windows). In your case, you will pick the **php 5.3 Thread Safe (TS) x86** version. The caveat here is I am unsure if this will work with the latest imagemagick Q16 DLL.

Copy the `php_imagick.dll` file to your PHP **ext** folder, and update your `php.ini` to include `extension=php_imagick.dll`. Then restart your WAMP server.

Run `phpinfo()` to ensure the imagick library is loaded properly.

Comment: Hi, I try it but i get a new error - "PHP Startup: imagick: Unable to initialize module Module Complied with module API=20121212 PHP compiled with module API=20100525 These options need to match"

Comment: @AnburajA Apparently, there are a lot of conflicting versions out there. Do you already have a `php_imagick.dll` extension added to your `php`?

Comment: Thank you for post. Imagick is working fine but now i facing a new problem. The problem is: "ImageMagick Number of supported formats: 0 " and "ImageMagick supported formats : no value". I'm checking at our godaddy server it have 198 file supported format. Now how can i fix the issues...

Comment: @AnburajA If you found this answer helpful, please mark it as accepted. Thanks. Meanwhile, please start a new question for the new problem to get more help from the rest of the community.